# Connecting input and output to the same bus

Tags: logic-gates, bus, register, logisim

I'm reading "But how do it know". And in register chapter, it talks about connecting both input and output pins to a bus. I tried to do it on Logisim but it shows red wires.
Can someone please explain what a bus really is in this case?
Here's the picture of the register subcircuit, and how it was built.

I'm new into electronics. Please ask if more info is needed. Thank you very much.
[image: Bus error]
[image: Building register]

Comment: They use tristate buffer for this, It has 2 input and 1 output. When you have to take input then, one input logic of that buffer makes output hiZ and when you have to give output, that input logic makes driver output equal to other input logic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic

Answer (score 0):

Normally multiple bus input connection is possible when used tri-state buffers.

[image]

If you use only elements from you picture No.2 inputs from the bus will conflict with inputs from the outside. For example an input from the bus set to 1 and an input from the outside can set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

> What is a bus?

Well, [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_(computing)) explains it much better and in more detail.

In short, a "bus" is a wire (or multiple wires if you need more bits) used by multiple bus members. "Bus" is the short form of "omnibus" that is Latin meaning "for all," and yes, it's the electrical instance of the public traffic vehicle.

Only one bus member is supposed to "drive" the bus at a time, but any other bus member is allowed to "read" the value. If no bus member drives the bus, it's value is undefined.

Commonly additional control lines are used to synchronize the access and to define the driving bus member.

---

If you replace the 2-input-AND gates by tri-state buffers ("Controlled Buffer" in Logicsim), you will get the desired behavior.

*Note: Actually, "tri-state" is "three-state" pronounced by non-native speakers. ;-)*

I created a 1-bit variant without nested circuits. There is also another bus member, realized by an input component with enabled Three-state feature.

These are different situations, starting from a "0" stored in the circuit:

1. No bus member drives the bus, and therefore it is floating ("X" in Logisim):
   [image]
2. The circuit drives the stored "0" to the bus if `OUTPUT ENABLE` is active:
   [image]
3. After the circuit releases the bus, the other bus member drives "1" to the bus:
   [image]
4. The circuit loads the "1" value from the bus if `LATCH` is active, `LATCH` will be deactivated after loading:
   [image]
5. The other bus member releases the bus after `LATCH` is deactivated, the circuit holds the value:
   [image]
6. The circuit drives the "1" to the bus if `OUTPUT ENABLE` is active:
   [image]

Re-create the circuit and play with it! Note, that you will have collisions on the bus if more than one bus member drives the bus with different values!

If Logisim moans about oscillation, it will stop the simulation, and you need to reset and enable it again.